# Calculation of duration from two dates during load data in datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have two columns which contains a start-date and end-date. I want to calculate the difference between those two.

I could do that after my grid has finished loading but is there any chance for doing that when I load my data to the grid?

**My short code snippet from my load code**

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("StartTime", typeof(DateTime));
dt.Columns.Add("EndTime", typeof(DateTime));
dt.Columns.Add("Duration", typeof(string));

foreach (string File in Files) {
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(MyXMLLocation + "\\" + File);
    XElement root = doc.Root;
    root.Descendants();

    string rootName = root.Name.LocalName;
    string logBookName = (string)root.Element("LogbookName");

    foreach (XElement timeSlot in root.Descendants("TimeSlot")) {
        DataRow newRow = dt.Rows.Add();

        newRow["StartTime"] = (DateTime)timeSlot.Elements().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "StartTime").FirstOrDefault();
        newRow["EndTime"] = (DateTime)timeSlot.Elements().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "EndTime").FirstOrDefault();
        newRow["Duration"] = "something";
```

Answer (score 0):

This will give you difference of time

```
    newRow["Duration"] = newRow["StartTime"].Subtract(newRow["EndTime"]).TotalMinutes;
```

Comment: Subtract is not available - BTW "EndTime" - "StartTime" would be correct.

Comment: yes it can be correct. if you want it into TimeSpan struct like **TimeSpan Duration = DateTime1 - DateTime2;** beacause TimeSpan  represents a duration of time or elapsed time.

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime start = (DateTime)timeSlot.Elements().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "StartTime").FirstOrDefault();
DateTime end = (DateTime)timeSlot.Elements().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "EndTime").FirstOrDefault();
newRow["StartTime"] = start.ToString();
newRow["EndTime"] = end.ToString();
newRow["Duration"] = (end-start).ToString();
```